# Как подставлять значения в запрос?

Tags: vue.js, axios

```
<template>
<form>
<h2>Вход</h2>
<p>
<label for="name">Ваше имя:</label>
<input type="text" id="name" v-model="login">
</p>
<p>
<label for="password">Ваш пароль:</label>
<input type="text" id="password" v-model="password">
</p>
<button type="button" name="button" @click="register">Войти</button>
</form>
</template>
 
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
 
export default {
data() {
return {
login: '',
password: ''
}
},
methods: {
register() {
axios.get('http://reg?login=${this.login}&password=${this.password}')
}
}
}
</script>
```

вместо `thislogin` и `thispassword` должны вставляться значения, но они почему-то не вставляются.

Comment: Приводите весь код. Этот запрос через Axios проблему не отражает. 99.9%, что Вы не указали эти переменные для инпутов как динамические, а поставили в value (должно быть `v-model="login"` и `v-model="password"`).

Comment: И ещё, по логике в бэкенд при записи данных используется `POST`, а `GET` - только для получения (за редким исключением, но у Вас точно не этот случай)

Comment: Не те кавычки. Вместо ' используйте ` (в axios.get)